# Looping non-jQuery animation works fine until loops back to starting point

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

Trying to loop through a set of sliding frames for a header features thing.

The "slide" divs...

```
<div class = "homeSlideHolder">
    <div class = "slide" id = "hs1" style="left: 0px;">
        <img src="img1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "slide" id = "hs2" style="left: 0px;">
        <img src="img2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class = "slide" id = "hs3" style="left: 0px;">
        <img src="img3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

...are to take turns at visibility by sliding off left each (n) secs and reassigning z-index to the new and old slides.

```
    function aniInit(){
        var slides = ["#hs1", "#hs2", "#hs3"];

        setTimeout(function(){aniInst(slides[0], slides)}, 6300);
    } 

    function aniInst(oldSlideID, slides){
        var oldSlide = document.querySelectorAll(oldSlideID);

        var nextSlideID = nextPrep(oldSlideID, slides);
        var nextSlide = document.querySelectorAll(nextSlideID);

        Velocity(oldSlide, {left: "-100%"}, 1000, function(){
            //give old slide a z-index of 0 and reset style.left 
            oldSlide[0].classList.add("SZIZero");
            oldSlide[0].classList.remove("SZIMax");
            oldSlide[0].style.left = 0; 
            //give next slide a z-index of 2
            nextSlide[0].classList.add("SZIMax");
            nextSlide[0].classList.remove("SZINext");
            setTimeout(function(){aniInst(nextSlideID, slides)}, 6300);
        });
    }

    function nextPrep(oldSlideID, slides){

        if (typeof slides[slides.indexOf(oldSlideID)+1] === "undefined"){
            var nextSlideID = slides[0];
        } else {
            var nextSlideID = slides[slides.indexOf(oldSlideID)+1];
        }

        var nextSlide = document.querySelectorAll(nextSlideID);
        //apply z-index of 1 to make sure next slide
        // is visible as the old one above it slides away
        nextSlide[0].classList.add("SZINext"); 
        nextSlide[0].classList.remove("SZIZero");

        return nextSlideID;
    }
```

Things are going well until #hs1's transition to #hs2 the second time around, at `Velocity(oldSlide,...` when I get `TypeError: L is undefined` from Velocity, and the animation and callback do not fire.

Comment: On which line in your script does that error get triggered? Is it the `Velocity(oldSlide,` line?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yap! editing the question to add that...

Comment: Your slide selectors are `["#hs1", "#hs2", "#hs3"]`, but none of those are shown in the code provided..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Aha. Mistake when simplifying the html...Question updated.

Comment: Your problem must be in your *actual* code, not in the code you `simplified`: it works here https://jsfiddle.net/ryep8kvc/ Post your actual code

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, not html issue. I switched the velocity source from [the download option](http://velocityjs.org/) to the CDN you used in jsfiddle and it worked fine. Thought it was my js... thanks for showing the way.